# Android Studio Generates bad manifest code

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-studio-2.2

I'm working on creating a simple test project that lets me manage a service with AlarmManager.  I somehow managed to create a new broadcast reciever with the name `+.java` in my `service` folder, so now Android Studio generates this invalid block of code in the AndroidManifest:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".service.+"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" />
```

Which generates the error

```
Error:(32) Tag <receiver> attribute name has invalid character '+'.
```

When I remove the block and rebuild, Android Studio regenerates the block and the error repeats.
Since this is a minor test project it's not a huge issue, but what if this happened in a larger project where I can't just nuke the whole directory?

My question is, how or where can I tweak what blocks of code Android Studio generates in order to resolve strange issues like this one?

Comment: "When I remove the block and rebuild, Android Studio regenerates the block and the error repeats" -- you may be editing the wrong file. When Android Studio encounters an error like this in the manifest, it typically opens up a generated manifest, rather than your original manifest where the problem comes from.

Comment: Have you invalidate cache and test that?

Comment: @CommonsWare You are extremely correct!  Feel free to re-phrase your suggestion and post it as an answer so I can accept it, that way you get credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [a long-standing issue in Android Studio](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=93290), where the IDE opens up the wrong edition of a file when it encounters an error. In the case of the manifest, Android Studio tends to open up a code-generated manifest, from the manifest merger process, rather than the actual manifest file that was the source of the error. As a result, the unwary (or the wary who are short on sleep) will edit the generated manifest... which then gets regenerated and blows away the edit.

The workaround is to double-check which file it is that you are editing when your changes seem to evaporate. A good night's sleep helps.

<sub>::yawns::</sub>

According to the issue, this should be fixed in Android Studio 2.3, which is working its way towards shipping sometime here in early 2017.